# Intellisense tip and XML returns comment (VS2008)

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, comments

I've found tooltips displayed by Intellisense when keying method name as very usefull but I can see only summary and params info - no returns comments

Eg - I can not see below comment:

```
 <returns> Enriched object</returns>
```

Is it a way to make it visible?

**EDIT**

Maybe you know the tool replacing standard Intellisense and displaying returns section

Comment: You can vote for this to be included in VS [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2317525-show-returns-and-value-contents-of-xml-documen).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Intellisense cannot display RETURNS statement indeed.

I have found [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/index.html) can do that!

Comment: VS 2017 still can't do this :)

Comment: It is now supported in VS, starting from v16.6.0. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63799941/825024).

Answer (score 4):

You can only see this in the compiled xml help. Intellisense only displays the method description. So it's a best practice to describe your method as "Returns xyz ...".