# Show <returns> xml tag into visual studio intellisense

Tags: visual-studio, documentation, intellisense, roslyn, xml-documentation

I added the `<returns>` xml tag to some of my methods but I can't see its content in IntelliSense.

Here is my code:

```
/// <summary>
/// we all live in a yellow summary
/// </summary>
/// <returns>what it returns</returns>
public int MyMethod()
{ .... }
```

Is there any way to show this content?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818694/how-to-display-return-value-summary-in-msvs-intellisense

Comment: Actually his question is related to mine. But it has an answer

Comment: Vote for it [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2317525-show-returns-and-value-contents-of-xml-documen). If there's enough demand, we might get it.

Comment: I've always wondered what the point of the return tag was. I mean, I make a point of filling in some basic detail, but I've never seen the point.

Comment: It is used in MSDN like automated documentation, which is based on your XML comments. Something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78f86at(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Intellisense tip and XML returns comment (VS2008)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006042/intellisense-tip-and-xml-returns-comment-vs2008)

Answer (score 6):

This has been finally implemented in Visual Studio 2019 v.16.6.0, only a decade later :)

From the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-v16.6#16.6.0):
[image: "Returns" tag contents]

Comment: Unfortunately it will only show up, if you hover over the method name. It is not shown when browsing through the overloads or while typing parameters.

Answer (score 3):

This currently does not work (Visual Studio 2017), and is an open issue:

https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/31618

One way to make it work is to install the ReSharper Visual Studio plugin (but this is paid-for).

Answer (score -2):

Sometimes it takes time for the IntelliSense to comprehend your code.
To verify that the  tag is there, try using the /doc compiler option like this:

> csc YourClass.cs /doc:YourClass.xml

If the  tag is present, then it's just a matter of IntelliSense issue which is usually fixed by its own or by restarting VS

Comment: This answer is incorrect. As of Visual Studio 2017, IntelliSense will never display the <return> tag.