# How to display the comment text which you set in the xml comment?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, documentation

When I create a method I use XML comment:

```
/// <summary>
/// Here goes the summary
/// </summary>
/// <param name="contextId">Some text about the parameter</param>
/// <returns>Some text which describes the return value</returns>
```

But when I want to use a method with this kind of commenting, I don't see the 'return' text. Is it possible to see this text in Visual Studio while you are using the method?

I am using VS 2010

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Same question as [Show <returns> xml tag into visual studio intellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464086/show-returns-xml-tag-into-visual-studio-intellisense)

Simple answer is no, you cannot see the `<returns>` tag content in the tooltip while using the method in question. The `<returns>` tag will instead be shown in the documentation file. A walkthrough of how to create that file is at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/csharpcodedocumentation.aspx

When writing your own code, your method summary should give a good understanding of what is being returned in the context of knowing the return type, e.g. the summary for MSFT's `System.Int32.Equals(System.Int32 obj)` (which has a boolean return type) is *Returns a value indicating whether this instance is equal to a specified System.Int32 value.*

Comment: It is now supported in VS, starting from v16.6.0. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63799941/825024).