# How to display return value summary in MSVS intellisense?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

In C# at least, MSVS intellisense displays information about functions and their parameters in the summary tags. There is also a return tag for description of the return value.

This page talks about viewing the function signature and parameters http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25cey46e(v=VS.90).aspx but what about the return value description?

Currently, I right click on the function and "go to definition" but i hope it can display inline as a tooltip.

Comment: Vote for it [here](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/2317525-show-returns-and-value-contents-of-xml-documen). If there's enough demand, we might get it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you are using Resharper, try CTRL+Shift+F1 (VS-Key Scheme) or CTRL+Q (ReSharper Key Scheme), it displays Quick documentation, inclusive return type. See http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/coding_assistance.html#Quick_Documentation

Comment: Was hoping for a native solution, but well. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: It is now supported in VS, starting from v16.6.0. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63799941/825024).