# How to display <returns> in intelisense?

Tags: resharper, intellisense, visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to display the returns info along with the summary in intelliSense when looking at a method in either visual studio (2019) and/or ReSharper?

For example given this method

```
/// <summary>
/// My method
/// </summary>
/// <returns>super cool info to have</returns>
public int NewMethod()
{
  ..
}
```

When trying to consume `NewMethod` i would like intellisense to display the returns info in addition to the summary info. Is it possible to enable this?

I could not get it to work with resharper playing with setting under options > environment > intellisence > completion behaviour nor could i find options to configure intellisense using visual studio options.

Comment: In fact, VS does not support intellisense for <Returns> tag and many users raises this issue. You can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464086/show-returns-xml-tag-into-visual-studio-intellisense) and does not work in VS2019. So far, the only way is to use Resharper extension. When you install all the workloads of Resharper and enable them in VS, you can see it by moving your cursor to the method body and click `Ctrl+Shirt+F1` to see the see it.

Comment: thanks @PerryQian-MSFT. I was not aware of the reSharper command `ctrl+shift+f1`

Can you please post this as a response rather then a comment so that i can mark it as the accepted answer?

Comment: Just a reminder, since my answer helps your issue, you could [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as l know, VS does not support Intellisense for `<Returns>` tag and it is a known issue, you can see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464086/show-returns-xml-tag-into-visual-studio-intellisense) and the latest VS2019 still does not support this behavior.

**So far, the only way is to use Resharper extension.**

> When trying to consume NewMethod i would like intellisense to display
>   the returns info in addition to the summary info. Is it possible to
>   enable this?

To use the Intellisense for `<Returns>` tag, you should move the cursor over the method body and press the shortcut `Ctrl +Shirt +F1` to show this behavior. See the picture below:

[image]

**In addition**, if you find this shortcut very cumbersome to use, you can assign a new shortcut in the option that you find convenient for yourself.

In `Tools-->Options-->Environment-->Keyboard` and then enter a new shortcut in the **red box** and then click **Assign**.

[image]

Comment: It is now supported in VS, starting from v16.6.0. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63799941/825024).